# Django fake model instanciation - No testunit

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to know if I can instanciate an empty fake model just with `id` of database record.
I found way to create mockup model, but I want a production-friendly solution.

Explanation of my issue :

I want to list users settings for users who choose to be displayed on public mode :

```
user_displayed_list = UserPublicProfile.objects.filter(
    displayed = True,
    ).only(
        'user_id',
        'is_premium',
    )

user_settings_list = []
for user_displayed in user_displayed_list:
    # I have to send user Instance to the next method :
    user_settings = self.get_user_settings(user_displayed.user)
    user_settings_list.append(user_settings)
    # But ’user_displayed.user’ run an new SQL query
```

I know I can improve my queryset as :

```
user_displayed_list = UserPublicProfile.objects.filter(
    displayed = True,
    ).select_related(
        'user'
    ).only(
        'user',
        'is_premium',
    )
```

But It makes an useless join because I need only the user `id` field in `get_user_settings()`:

The `get_user_settings()` method (it could help to understand context):

```
def get_user_settings(self, user)
    user_settings = UserSettings.objects.get(user = user)
    return user_settings
```

In real project, this method run more business feature

Is there a way to instanciate a User model instance with only `id` field filled ?

I don't want to use a custom empty class coded for this purpose. I really want an object User.

I didn't find anything for that. If it's possible, I could use it by this way :

```
for user_displayed in user_displayed_list:
    FakeUser = User.objects.create_fake(id = user_displayed.user_id)
    # I have to send user Instance to the next method :
    user_settings = self.get_user_settings(FakeUser)
```

Comment: If the next method only needs the id why does it take a user instance? Just pass it the id `user_displayed.user_id` and use that `UserSettings.objects.get(user_id=user_id)`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, because it's a legacy method, already used many times in the project.

Comment: `user = User()` and `user.pk = user_displayed.user_id`? That should effectively be enough. Although note if someone later calls `save` on this instance you might either get an error or remove data accidentally.

Comment: I didn't think, I could do that so easily. Thank you, it works.
Can you post it as an anwser ? so users'll quick find the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete models, I'm assuming a bit. Assuming that `UserSettings` has a ForeignKey to `User`. Same for `UserPublicProfile`. Or `User` has ForeignKey to `UserSettings`. Works as well.

Assuming that, I see two solutions.

## Solution #1; use the ORM to full potential

Just saw your comment about the 'legacy method, used many times'.

Django relations are very smart. They accept either the object or the ID of a ForeignKey.
You'd imagine this only works with a `User`. But if you pass the `id`, Django ORM will help you out.

```py
def get_user_settings(self, user)
    user_settings = UserSettings.objects.get(user = user)
    return user_settings
```

So in reality, these work the same:

```py
UserSettings.objects.get(user=1)
UserSettings.objects.get(user_id=1)
```

Which means this should work, without a extra query:

```py
user_displayed_list = UserPublicProfile.objects.filter(
    displayed = True,
    ).only(
        'user_id',
        'is_premium',
    )

user_settings_list = []
for user_displayed in user_displayed_list:
    # I have to send user Instance to the next method :
    user_settings = self.get_user_settings(user_displayed.user_id) # pass the user_id instead of the object.
    user_settings_list.append(user_settings)
```

## Solution #2: chain relations

Another solution, again, still assuming quite a bit ;)
It would think you can chain the model together.
Assuming these FK exists: UserPublicProfile -> User -> UserSetting.
You could do this:

```py
user_displayed_list = UserPublicProfile.objects.filter(
    displayed = True,
    ).select_related(
        'user', 'user__usersettings', # depends on naming of relations
    ).only(
        'user',
        'is_premium',
    )


for user_displayed in user_displayed_list:
    # I have to send user Instance to the next method :
    user_settings = user_displayed.user.usersettings # joined, so should cause no extra queries. Depends on naming of relations.
    user_settings_list.append(user_settings)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Solution #1 need to rewrite legacy method.
Solution #2 add useless database joins.
I got a correct answer on question's comments

Comment: You're welcome. Bit hard to help without full models or context.

Comment: Yes that's why I explained that I wanted to create a dummy model without adding joins. But I understand, it's pretty difficulte to comprehend the real need.